# R Convert to date from multiple formats

Tags: r, as.date

I need to convert a string of dates that is in multiple formats to valid dates.

e.g.

```
dates <- c("01-01-2017","02-01-2017","12-01-2016","20160901","20161001", "20161101")

> as.Date(dates, format=c("%m-%d-%Y","%Y%m%d"))
[1] "2017-01-01" NA           "2016-12-01" "2016-09-01" NA           "2016-11-01"
```

two dates show as NA

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is pretty much I wrote the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package for:

```
R> dates <- c("01-01-2017","02-01-2017","12-01-2016","20160901","20161001", 
+             "20161101")
R> library(anytime)
R> anydate(dates)
[1] "2017-01-01" "2017-02-01" "2016-12-01" "2016-09-01" 
[5] "2016-10-01" "2016-11-01"
R>
```

Parse any *sane* input reliably and *without explicit format* or *origin* or other line noise.

That being said, not starting ISO style with the year *is* asking for potential trouble, so `02-03-2017` could be February 3 or March 2. I am following the North American convention I too consider somewhat broken -- but is so darn prevalent.  Do yourself a favour and try to limit inputs to ISO dates, at least ISO order YYYYMMDD.

Comment: To clarify, `anydate()` gives priority to mdy over dmy?

Comment: Yes. [See the formats](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/blob/master/src/anytime.cpp#L43-L106) which you can also list from within.

Comment: I found this to be a little faster  `as.Date(ifelse(grepl("-", dates),
                           as.Date(dates, format = c("%m-%d-%Y")),
                           as.Date(dates, format = c("%Y%m%d"))), origin = "1970-01-01")`

Comment: Is there any way to simply change the origin? I find this function really useful but have a need to change the origin when dealing with integer to "1899-12-30" because of Excel.

Comment: Hi @Croote I _guess_ one could. We use it as a compile-time constant and we could, I suppose, change it.  With a whole new layer of testing so there is 'cost'.  It may be simpler to write a local `fromExcel()` helper.  It you want to follow up open an issue ticket with some sample data/

Comment: Hi , Thanks, I think I might just do that. In my company we are stuck pulling client data from excel all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried library(anytime), however for big data did not work.
Then, I found useful this sequence:

```
df$Date2 <- format(as.Date(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"), "%d/%m/%y")

df$Date2 <- as.Date(df$Date2,"%d/%m/%y")
```

It worked for me to "8/10/2005" as well as "08/13/05" in the same column.